# Expected value after a chain of events?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, noise

my problem is the following. I have a scalar variable, which changes with a certain noise every step:

Step 0: $x_0 = \nu_0$,

Step 1: $x_1 = s\cdot x_0 + \nu_1$,

...

Step i: $x_i = s\cdot x_{i-1} + \nu_i$,

where $s$ is positive scalar value, $\nu_i$ - zero-mean normally distributed gaussian RV (noise). Now, at certain step $k$, absolute value of $x_i$ exceeds a scalar threshold value $y$. Hence, $k$ is also a random variable. The question is, how to find the expected value of $k$ give the distribution of $\nu$, $s$ and $y$?

I'll appreciate any advice on how to approach the problem! For now I'm able to predict the distribution of absolute value of $x_i$ at any step $i$ (it is a half-normal distribution with parameters dependent on $\nu$ and $s$), but I'm totally failing to make a step towards finding the distribution of $k$.

Comment: Where are we on this question ? did you get your answer ? if so please accept it or at least vote up

Answer (score 1):

You are summing Gaussians, so basically

$$x_0\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$$
$$x_1\sim N(0,\sigma^2+s\sigma^2)$$
$$x_2\sim N(0,\sigma^2+s\sigma^2+s^2\sigma^2)$$
And in general, using [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)
$$x_k\sim N(0,\sigma^2(\frac{s^k-1}{s-1}))$$

Comment: Hi Uri, thanks for the answer. This is exactly the moment I arrived at - moreover, from this it is easy to infer how the absolute value of $x_k$ is distributed (half-normal). My problem is at the next step, namely, how to infer from it the expected value of $k$ for which $|x_k|$ crosses the threshold $y$.

Comment: Take a look at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution

Comment: The expected value is $$\sigma \sqrt{\frac{\pi (s^k-1)}{2(s-1)}}$$

Comment: I think we have some misunderstanding on this question. Maybe my formulation isn't very good - feel free to criticize.
Again, there are two random variables - $x_i$ and $k$, where $x_i$ is the state of the system at timestep $i$, and $k$ is the timestep at which $x_k > \lambda$. Your answer is concerned with $E[|x_i|]$, and it is correct - but, as I said, my problem is to find from it the $E[k]$.